# Sorting individual columns of an array

Tags: python, sorting, columnsorting

Given an input

```
array = [
[1,2,-1,-1,2],
[3,-1,-1,-1,-1],
[-1,-1,-1,3,2]
]
```

I want to transform it into this:

```
new_array = [
[-1,-1,-1,-1,-1],
[1,-1,-1,-1,2],
[3,2,-1,3,2]
]
```

That is, for each column, I want elements to stay in their relative places, but move any `-1` to the "top" of the column.

I know thanks to a previous question that i can use a something along the lines of `sorted(array, key=lambda x: x==-1)` to sort all the `-1` values to the top. I could also use `sorted(array, key = lambda x: x[i])` to sort the array based on column `i`. However, even combining these doesn't do what I would like it to do, as I'd like to sort each column separately based on the `-1` key above. I've tried playing around with some different lambda functions, but this is the first time I've seen them so I'm not really sure how they work yet. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: can you specify how you want to transform the array? You example doesn't make sense to me

Answer (score 2):

you can use numpy

```
import numpy as np

array = [
[1,2,-1,-1,2],
[3,-1,-1,-1,-1],
[-1,-1,-1,3,2]]

np_array = np.array(array)
sorted_np_array = np.sort(np_array, axis=0)

sorted_array = sorted_np_array.tolist()
```

Answer (score 2):

```
array = [
[1,2,-1,-1,2],
[3,-1,-1,-1,-1],
[-1,-1,-1,3,2]
]

list(zip(*[sorted(i) for i in list(zip(*array))]))
```

Here you go a single line list comprehension for your question